# BigCommerce, How to add a custom quick view button

Tags: bigcommerce

BigCommerce, How to add a custom quick view button anywhere other than the one that shows on hover like in code?

```
    <div class="ProductImage QuickView" data-product="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">
    %%GLOBAL_ProductThumb%%
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been 4 months since your original post so I'm not sure if you need this anymore, but others might find it useful.

In your CategoryProductsItem.html you can insert the following code

```
<style>.QuickView.yourClass .QuickViewBtn{background-color:transparent !important;} .Quickview.yourClass{position:relative; display:block; padding:0;}</style><div class="QuickView yourClass btn Small icon-Add To Cart" data-product="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%" style="display:block !important; visibility: visible;">Add to cart</div>
```

I use this to basically give the customer the ability to change quantities in the add to cart popup(which is actually now just using the quick view one).
The QuickViewContent.html is where you could add in the product description if you wanted with

```
%%GLOBAL_QuickViewProductDescription%%
```

the visibility and block properties are important so aren't forced to hover for the button to be visible